# Fastbert: BertDataBunch error for multilabel text classification

Tags: nlp, pytorch

I'm following the FastBert tutorial from huggingface https://medium.com/huggingface/introducing-fastbert-a-simple-deep-learning-library-for-bert-models-89ff763ad384

The problem is this the code is not exactly reproducible. The main issue I'm facing is the dataset preparation. In the tutorial, this dataset is used https://www.kaggle.com/c/jigsaw-toxic-comment-classification-challenge/data

But, if I set-up the folder structure according the tutorial, and place the dataset files in the folders I get errors with the databunch.

```
databunch = BertDataBunch(args['data_dir'], LABEL_PATH, args.model_name, train_file='train.csv', val_file='val.csv',
                          test_data='test.csv',
                          text_col="comment_text", label_col=label_cols,
                          batch_size_per_gpu=args['train_batch_size'], max_seq_length=args['max_seq_length'], 
                          multi_gpu=args.multi_gpu, multi_label=True, model_type=args.model_type)
```

It complains about the file format being wrong. How should I format the dataset, labels for this dataset with fastbert?

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, you can use the notebook from GitHub for FastBert.

https://github.com/kaushaltrivedi/fast-bert/blob/master/sample_notebooks/new-toxic-multilabel.ipynb

2. There is a small tutorial in the FastBert README on how to process the dataset before using.

**Create a DataBunch object**

```
The databunch object takes training, validation and test csv files and converts the data into internal representation for BERT, RoBERTa, DistilBERT or XLNet. The object also instantiates the correct data-loaders based on device profile and batch_size and max_sequence_length.

from fast_bert.data_cls import BertDataBunch

databunch = BertDataBunch(DATA_PATH, LABEL_PATH,
                          tokenizer='bert-base-uncased',
                          train_file='train.csv',
                          val_file='val.csv',
                          label_file='labels.csv',
                          text_col='text',
                          label_col='label',
                          batch_size_per_gpu=16,
                          max_seq_length=512,
                          multi_gpu=True,
                          multi_label=False,
                          model_type='bert')

File format for train.csv and val.csv
index   text    label
0   Looking through the other comments, I'm amazed that there aren't any warnings to potential viewers of what they have to look forward to when renting this garbage. First off, I rented this thing with the understanding that it was a competently rendered Indiana Jones knock-off.    neg
1   I've watched the first 17 episodes and this series is simply amazing! I haven't been this interested in an anime series since Neon Genesis Evangelion. This series is actually based off an h-game, which I'm not sure if it's been done before or not, I haven't played the game, but from what I've heard it follows it very well     pos
2   his movie is nothing short of a dark, gritty masterpiece. I may be bias, as the Apartheid era is an area I've always felt for.  pos

In case the column names are different than the usual text and labels, you will have to provide those names in the databunch text_col and label_col parameters.

labels.csv will contain a list of all unique labels. In this case the file will contain:

pos
neg

For multi-label classification, labels.csv will contain all possible labels:

severe_toxic
obscene
threat
insult
identity_hate

The file train.csv will then contain one column for each label, with each column value being either 0 or 1. Don't forget to change multi_label=True for multi-label classification in BertDataBunch.
id  text    toxic   severe_toxic    obscene     threat  insult  identity_hate
0   Why the edits made under my username Hardcore Metallica Fan were reverted?  0   0   0   0   0   0
0   I will mess you up  1   0   0   1   0   0

label_col will be a list of label column names. In this case it will be:

['toxic','severe_toxic','obscene','threat','insult','identity_hate']
```

So, just keep the train.csv, val.csv (just make a copy of train.csv), and test.csv inside data/

In the labels folder, keep a labels.csv with the following contents.

```
severe_toxic
obscene
threat
insult
identity_hate
```